# Catching unhandled exception Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, exception, service

I've written a window service like this:

```
  public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private Thread writerThread;
    private Thread messageThread;
    private bool stopNow;

    public Service1()
    {
    }

    private void MessageThread()
    {
        while (stopNow == false)
        {
            try
            {
               //Do Something
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                GLogWriter.Write(String.Format("Critical exception {0}. Inner Exception {1} ", e.Message, e.InnerException.Message), LogCategories.Generic, TraceEventType.Critical);
                OnStop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void WriterThread()
    {
        bool checkGruppoIndirizzi = true;

        while (stopNow == false)
        {
            try
            {
                //Do something else
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                GLogWriter.Write(String.Format("Critical exception {0}. Inner Exception {1} ", e.Message, e.InnerException.Message), LogCategories.Generic, TraceEventType.Critical);
                OnStop();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        GLogWriter.Write("SERVICE IS STARTING", LogCategories.Generic, TraceEventType.Information);

        this.stopNow = false;

        writerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.WriterThread));
        writerThread.Start();

        this.messageThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.MessageThread));
        this.messageThread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        GLogWriter.Write("SERVICE IS STOPPING", LogCategories.Generic, TraceEventType.Information);
        stopNow = true;
        writerThread.Join(1000);
        messageThread.Join(1000);
        GLogWriter.Write("SERVICE STOP SUCCESSFUL", LogCategories.Generic, TraceEventType.Information);
    }
}
```

}

The problem is when i Catch an exception apparently the OnStop() is not being called and the service stops promptly without logging the "SERVICE IS STOPPING" messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnStop()` method is not something that should be called when the thread(s) of your service stop working. It is a special procedure which is supposed to be called by Service Control Manager. In other words, `OnStop()` is the procedure that should stop the service normally, when you need to. Something calls  `OnStop()` -> service is stopped. It is not the other way around (something happens within the service -> thread(s) exit -> `OnStop()` is called)

Comment: @Federico normally you'd want to keep your `OnStop()` override. Without it you loose the way to gracefully stop the service. `OnStop()` is like an exit option for a GUI application. You may remove it, and user will need to kill the app from task manager, but generally it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at Windows Event Log to see what kind of error or exception you are getting.  If it is a program exception , the definitely it would have been caught on catch. So i suspect that service throw exception at system level.

That should be diagnosed through Event Log.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the following line:

```
GLogWriter.Write(String.Format("Critical exception {0}. Inner Exception {1} ", e.Message, e.InnerException.Message), LogCategories.Generic, TraceEventType.Critical);
```

`InnerException` is not always an object, rather it is often `null`.

Change that line to:

```
GLogWriter.Write(String.Format("Critical exception {0}. Inner Exception {1} ", e.Message, ((e.InnerException == null) ? string.Empty : e.InnerException.Message)), LogCategories.Generic, TraceEventType.Critical);
```

Comment: Apparently this doesn't change anything because that line is logged succesfully and the innerException is not null. The problem is the call to OnStop() doesn't work. Also i think instead using the tertiary operator this line is better `(e.InnerException ?? string.Emtpy)`